# wordpress custom fields then import RSS Feed

Tags: xml, wordpress, import, custom-fields, rss2

I want to import in my Wordpress blog new posts with RSS Feed 2.0. I generated standart XML file for wordpress import and added some custom fields: thumbnail, video and duration.
Here example:

```
<rss version="2.0" 
xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" 
xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/" 
xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
<title>Title</title>
<link>Somelink</link>
<language>en</language>
<channel>
<item>
     <title>Title</title>
     <pubDate>Mon, 29 Aug 2016 04:24:00 +0000</pubDate>
     <description>description</description>
     <content:encoded><![CDATA[some text]>content:encoded>

    <Category>category 1</Category>
    <Category>category 2</Category>

    <wp:postmeta>
    <wp:meta_key>duration</wp:meta_key>
    <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[25:44]]></wp:meta_value>
    </wp:postmeta>

    <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[videoswiper-embed-thumb]]></wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[http://example.com/thumb.jpg]]>     </wp:meta_value>
    </wp:postmeta>
    <wp:postmeta>
           <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[videoswiper-embed-code]]></wp:meta_key>
           <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="[http://example.com/video.mp4"/>]]></wp:meta_value>
    </wp:postmeta>
</item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

I've been successful at creating posts but custom type values are empty.
In addition to the above. I use a custom theme where this three fields are already exists(empty by default).

What I'am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
<content:encoded><![CDATA[some text]>content:encoded>
```

or

```
<content:encoded><![CDATA[some text]]></content:encoded>
```